# Method Not Implemented GET to wp-admin/post.php not supported

Tags: errors

When I save a draft post I get this error. It hasn't happened before, and it only happens with one post. We are using commercial hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions to this usually revolve around the mod_security Apache module. However this was very specific to the one post. In the end I tracked it down to this fragment of HTML:

```
CD.</li>
```

If I chopped it down to just this:
    CD.<
it would work, but adding that / made it fail.

I don't have ready access to the security rules that are set up on this hosting, though I could ask them. My theory is though that this fragment of HTML looks like a malicious script and is triggering some rule. To get round it I changed CD to C.D.